# Magento 2.1:- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /mage2/shipping /app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php:90

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, plugin

> app/code/Test/Shipping/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin name="shipping_test" type="Test\Shipping\Plugin\Shipping" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Shipping\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Test\Shipping\Model\Source\Allshippingmethods;
use Test\Shipping\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Shipping
{
    /**
     * Code of the carrier
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code='Shipping';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * Rate result data
     *
     * @var Result
     */
    protected $_result;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface
     */
    protected $_rateCollector;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        RateCollectorInterface $rateCollector,
        \Test\Shipping\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $data = []
    ) { 
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->_rateCollector = $rateCollector;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of key-value pairs of all available methods
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $group_info=$this->helper->getAllMethods();
        $carriers=array();
        foreach ($group_info as &$carrier) {
            $carriers[$group_info['label']]=$group_info['label'];
        }
        return $carriers;
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        if (empty($this->_result)) {
            $this->_result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->_result;
    }

    public function aroundCollectCarrierRates($proceed, $carrierCode, $request)
    {
        $result = $proceed();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $gid = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            $group_info = $this->helper->getGroupData($gid);
            //var_dump($group_info);exit;
        }

        $result->getResult()->append($group_info);

        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Here I want **var_dump($group_info)** in return.
Because I got all methods set in checkout/cart page.

> app/code/Test/Shipping/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Shipping\Helper;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Test\Shipping\Model\Source\Allshippingmethods;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $urlInterface;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_asm;

    protected $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigObject,
        Allshippingmethods $Allshippingmethods,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfigObject;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_asm = $Allshippingmethods;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    public function getGroupData($id)
    {
        $db = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test_shipping WHERE customer_group=' . $id);
        $row = $result->fetch();
        $values=$row['carriers'];//print_r($values);exit;
        $split=explode(",",$values);
        $count = count($split);

        $methods=$this->_asm->toOptionArray();

        foreach ($methods as $j => $inner) {
            if(!empty($inner['value'])){
                foreach ($inner['value'] as $key => $value) {
                    if (in_array($value['value'], $split)) {      
                       unset($methods[$j]['value'][$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $methods;
    }

    public function getAllMethods()
    {
        $methods=$this->_asm->toOptionArray();

        return $methods;
    }
}

?>
```

> app/code/Test/Shipping/Model/Source/Allshippingmethods.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Shipping\Model\Source;

/**
 * Class Allshippingmethods
 */
class Allshippingmethods implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
   /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_shippingConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_shippingConfig = $shippingConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Return array of carriers.
     * If $isActiveOnlyFlag is set to true, will return only active carriers
     *
     * @param bool $isActiveOnlyFlag
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray($isActiveOnlyFlag = false)
    {
        $methods = [['value' => '', 'label' => '']];
        $carriers = $this->_shippingConfig->getAllCarriers();

        foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierModel) {
            if (!$carrierModel->isActive() && (bool)$isActiveOnlyFlag === true) {
                continue;
            }
            $carrierMethods = $carrierModel->getAllowedMethods();
            if (!$carrierMethods) {
                continue;
            }
            $carrierTitle = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/title',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );

            $methods[$carrierCode] = ['label' => $carrierTitle, 'value' => []];
            foreach ($carrierMethods as $methodCode => $methodTitle) {
                $methods[$carrierCode]['value'][] = [
                    'value' => $carrierCode . '_' . $methodCode,
                    'label' => '[' . $carrierCode . '] ' . $methodTitle,
                ];
            }
        }
        return $methods;
    }
}

?>
```

Below i got the error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /mage2/shipping
/app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php:90
Stack trace:
#0 /mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142
): Test\Shipping\Plugin\Shipping-&gt;aroundCollectCarrierRates(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model
\Shipping\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'dhl', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest
))
#1 /mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor
.php(91): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor-&gt;___callPlugins('collectCarrierR...', Array
, Array)
#2 /mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209):
 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor-&gt;collectCarrierRates('dhl', Object(Magento\Quote\Model
\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#3 /mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor
.php(76): Mage in <b>/mage2/shipping/app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin
/Shipping.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/1070442461519"
}]}}
```

What do I do now ?

Comment: Line 90:  `$result = $proceed()`; It should be  `$result = $proceed;` right?

Comment: @AnkitShah Yes, i also try for that.. And error removed but i got in response only blank array like this `[ ]`

Answer (score 2):

your `aroundCollectCarrierRates` is declared wrongly.
The first parameter should be the instance of the class you are pluginizing.
[See this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods) for more details.

Your method should look like this:

```
public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
    $proceed, 
    $carrierCode, 
    $request
) {
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: You are right @Marius, But When i use this 

`aroundCollectCarrierRates(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject, \callable $proceed, $carrierCode, $request)`

I got this error:- 

`<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'callable' (T_CALLABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING
) in <b>/mage2/shipping/app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping
.php</b> on line <b>88</b><br />
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/1322575338538"
}]}}`

Comment: see my edit. Remove `\callable` from the method definition.

Comment: I also remove \callable.. Now new error create like this:-

`[2016-09-21 07:36:09] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectCarrierRates()`

Comment: remove just the word `\callable`, not the variable. See my edit.

Comment: Ya i remove only `\callable` , not the variable. Like as your answer Marius.

See the Screenshot here :- http://prntscr.com/ckjbkv

Comment: @PayalPatel: It should be `\Closure` not `\callable`

Comment: It is working fine